# ROI треугольной/трапециевидной формы

Tags: c++, opencv

Как задать в С++ d OpenCV 3 ROI треугольной или трапециевидной формы?

Благодарю

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Цель какая? Если для копирования/выделения куска картинки, то надо использовать маску - создать Image того же размера с форматом пиксела 8UC1, отрисовать маску белым, и использовать её как аргумент функций вроде

```
 result.copyTo(source,  mask);
```

заполнение маски

```
 vector<vector<Point>> contours;
 contours.push_back(vector<Point>());
 contours[0].push_back(Point1);
 ...
 drawContours( mask,contours,0, Scalar(255),CV_FILLED, 8);
```

Для расчётов же применяются только ROI-прямоугольники.

Comment: Есть задача обнаружения дорожной разметки. То есть должен обрабатываться треугольный/трапециевидный сектор кадров, который содержит линии разметки полосы движения.

Comment: Что значит обрабатываться? Хочется сэкономить время, не обсчитывая края или ещё что для всей картинки? Увы, не выйдет. Можно только исключить обнаружение особенностей в нежелательной области наложением всё тех же масок

Comment: Ну то есть алгоритм должен выдавать как дорожную разметку только прямые линии, находящиеся в ROI непосредственно у полотна дороги ( отсюда и форма трапеции в нижней части кадра) А другие прямые линии, такие как соседняя разметка, дорожные знаки, здания алгоритм не должен видеть.

Объясните, как именно задавать такую маску? Исходный кадр с камеры у меня хранится в 
      Mat frame;

Comment: И как выглядит в виде кода "обрисовка" маски?

Comment: Маска - нарисовать что-то типа `drawContours( mask, массив или вектор координат углов трапеции, Scalar(255),CV_FILLED, 8 );`

Comment: Теперь проблема. Не могу задать вектор координат углов трапеции. Все примеры показывают, что вектор типа <vector<Point>>  записывается от других функций, а мне необходимо вручную задать вершины трапеции. Подскажите, как это сделать синтаксически?

Comment: В пост добавил. drawContours не единственный путь, можно и просто полигон нарисовать fillConvexPoly