# Формат инициализации вектора типа Vec2i

Tags: c++, opencv

Подскажите, пожалуйста, синтаксис, как инициализировать вектор типа .

`vector <Vec2i>` corners = [.................];

Спасибо!

Comment: Мне этот вектор нужен в частности как параметр функции drawContours( frame_gray, corners, Scalar(255),CV_FILLED, 8 ); Он должен задавать требуемое количество вершин многоугольной маски

Comment: Отвечено там: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/828548/